# What is Anterhise?

Tags: terminology

In the [pirate song by Henry Every](https://ebba.english.ucsb.edu/ballad/22206/xml), there are the lines:

> Then away from this Climate and temperate Zone,
> To one that's more torrid, you'll hear I am gone,
> With an hundred and fifty brave Sparks of this Age,
> Wo are fully resolved their Foes to engage.
>
> These Northern Parts are not thrifty for me,
> I'll rise the **Anterhise,** that some Men shall see
> I am not afraid to let the World know,
> That to the South-Seas and to Persia I'll go.

I tried but failed to find any mention of *Anterhise* in any dictionary or online. Any tips?

Comment: Based entirely on the scant context given, perhaps it's the name of a pirate flag, like the Jolly Roger.

Comment: I wonder if it’s a very odd spelling of ‘ancient’, which was at the time an alternate version of ‘ensign’, meaning the ship’s flag? That spelling isn’t mentioned in the OED, though ‘antient’ is.

Comment: It's polite and useful to link your source: [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Copy_of_Verses,_Composed_by_Captain_Henry_Every,_Lately_Gone_to_Sea_to_seek_his_Fortune) is a copy of the song.

Comment: Since it's mentioned in connection with going south rather than north, maybe it's a garbled version of _Antipodes_?

Comment: Some early versions of the ballad have "I'll raise the Antortick" (presumably a misspelling of Antarctic), discussing sailing from north to south. And I found a variant with "Anterise". It's hard to see "Anter(h)ise" as being a variant, typo, or misreading of Antarctic/Antortick or even Antipodes but I guess it's possible. For variants, see "Bold Captain Avery in the Privy Council: Early Variants of a Broadside Ballad from the Pepys Collection", Joel H. Baer, Folk Music Journal Vol. 7, No. 1 (1995), pp. 4-26 (23 pages)

Comment: [Antares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antares)